# numpy: Why is there a difference between (x,1) and (x, ) dimensionality

Tags: python, numpy

I am wondering why in numpy there are one dimensional array of dimension (length, 1) and also one dimensional array of dimension (length, ) w/o a second value.

I am running into this quite frequently, e.g. when using `np.concatenate()`  which then requires a `reshape` step beforehand (or I could directly use `hstack`/`vstack`).

I can't think of a reason why this behavior is desirable. Can someone explain?

**Edit:**
It was suggested by one of the comments that my question is a possible duplicate. I am more interested in the underlying working logic of Numpy and not that there is a distinction between 1d and 2d arrays which I think is the point of the mentioned thread.

Comment: `(x,)` refers to a vector, not a matrix.

Comment: NumPy is built around n-dimensional arrays, not matrices.

Comment: @kennytm Thanks for the input, but what is the reason that a vector would not be represented as `(x,1)`?

Comment: @user2357112 reworded accordingly

Comment: A numpy array with shape (x, 1) is a *two-dimensional array*.  The second dimension just happens to have length 1.  A numpy array with shape (x,) is a *one-dimensional array*.  It has no second dimension.  For much of numpy, you can stop thinking about "vectors" and "matrices", and just think about n-dimensional arrays.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [numpy: 1D array with various shape](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15680593/numpy-1d-array-with-various-shape)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The data of a `ndarray` is stored as a 1d buffer - just a block of memory.  The multidimensional nature of the array is produced by the `shape` and `strides` attributes, and the code that uses them.

The `numpy` developers chose to allow for an arbitrary number of dimensions, so the shape and strides are represented as tuples of any length, including 0 and 1.

In contrast MATLAB was built around FORTRAN programs that were developed for matrix operations.  In the early days everything in MATLAB was a 2d matrix.  Around 2000 (v3.5) it was generalized to allow more than 2d, but never less.  The `numpy` `np.matrix` still follows that old 2d MATLAB constraint.

If you come from a MATLAB world you are used to these 2 dimensions, and the distinction between a row vector and column vector.  But in math and physics that isn't influenced by MATLAB, a vector is a 1d array.  Python lists are inherently 1d, as are `c` arrays.  To get 2d you have to have lists of lists or arrays of pointers to arrays, with `x[1][2]` style of indexing.

Look at the shape and strides of this array and its variants:

```
In [48]: x=np.arange(10)

In [49]: x.shape
Out[49]: (10,)

In [50]: x.strides
Out[50]: (4,)

In [51]: x1=x.reshape(10,1)

In [52]: x1.shape
Out[52]: (10, 1)

In [53]: x1.strides
Out[53]: (4, 4)

In [54]: x2=np.concatenate((x1,x1),axis=1)

In [55]: x2.shape
Out[55]: (10, 2)

In [56]: x2.strides
Out[56]: (8, 4)
```

MATLAB adds new dimensions at the end.  It orders its values like a `order='F'` array, and can readily change a (n,1) matrix to a (n,1,1,1).  `numpy` is default `order='C'`, and readily expands an array dimension at the start.  Understanding this is essential when taking advantage of broadcasting.

Thus `x1 + x` is a (10,1)+(10,) => (10,1)+(1,10) => (10,10)

Because of broadcasting a `(n,)` array is more like a `(1,n)` one than a `(n,1)` one.  A 1d array is more like a row matrix than a column one.

```
In [64]: np.matrix(x)
Out[64]: matrix([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])

In [65]: _.shape
Out[65]: (1, 10)
```

The point with `concatenate` is that it requires matching dimensions.  It does not use broadcasting to adjust dimensions.  There are a bunch of `stack` functions that ease this constraint, but they do so by adjusting the dimensions before using `concatenate`.  Look at their code (readable Python).

So a proficient numpy user needs to be comfortable with that generalized `shape` tuple, including the empty `()` (0d array), `(n,)` 1d, and up.  For more advanced stuff understanding strides helps as well (look for example at the strides and shape of a transpose).

Comment: Thanks this was very helpful for understanding the origin of Numpy's behavior. I am wondering now  what the benefit of these 1-dimensional arrays is. Why are they not hidden under the hood and to the user everything is minimum a `(x,1)` array? Are there specific cases where `(x,)` arrays have advantages?

Comment: A `(x,1)` displays as a column.  A `(1,x)` as a row, but with an extra set of [].  I generate 1d arrays all the time, e.g. `np.arange(10)`.  I may reshape it to `(5,2)`.  Only when I need to broadcast it do I add the trailing `, `[:,None]`.

Comment: can we say that `(x,)` is a Vector where as `(x,1)` is a Matrix?

Answer (score 3):

Much of it is a matter of syntax. This tuple `(x)` isn't a tuple at all (just a redundancy). `(x,)`, however, is.

The difference between (x,) and (x,1) goes even further. You can take a look into the examples of previous questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16995071/numpy-array-that-is-n-1-and-n). Quoting the example from it, this is an 1D numpy array:

```
>>> np.array([1, 2, 3]).shape
(3,)
```

But this one is 2D:

```
>>> np.array([[1, 2, 3]]).shape
(1, 3)
```

[Reshape does not make a copy unless it needs to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17869840/numpy-vector-n-1-dimension-n-dimension-conversion) so it should be safe to use.