# unify numpy.ndarray shape in python, need to unify shape which is (900,1) and (900,)

Tags: python, numpy

I have two numpy.ndarray, one's shape is (900,1) and the other's shape is (900,) what's the difference and how to unify them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between numpy.array shape (R, 1) and (R,)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22053050/difference-between-numpy-array-shape-r-1-and-r)

Comment: Or this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38402227/numpy-why-is-there-a-difference-between-x-1-and-x-dimensionality