# What's the difference between (N,) and (N,1) in numpy?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I am not sure about the difference between (N,) and (N,1) in numpy. Assuming both are some features, they have same N dimension, and both have one sample. What's the difference?

```
a = np.ones((10,))
print(a.shape) #(10,)
b = np.ones((10,1))
print(b.shape) #(10,1)
```

Comment: A couple of duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22053050/difference-between-numpy-array-shape-r-1-and-r, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38402227/numpy-why-is-there-a-difference-between-x-1-and-x-dimensionality

Answer (score 12):

In Python, `(10,)` is a one-tuple (the `,` being necessary to distinguish it from the use of parentheses for grouping: `(10)` just means `10`), whereas `(10,1)` is a pair (a 2-tuple). So `np.ones((10,))` creates a one-dimensional array of size 10, whereas `np.ones((10,1))` creates a two-dimensional array of dimension 10×1. This is directly analogous to, say, the difference between a single number and a one-dimensional array of length `1`.

Answer (score 10):

The difference is that `a` is a one dimensional array. Like this:

```
[1,1,1]
```

And `b` is a multidimensinal array. Like this:

```
[[1],
 [1],
 [1]]
```