# Why does scikit-learn demand different data shapes for different regressors?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I always find myself reshaping my data when I'm working with `sklearn`, and it's irritating and makes my code ugly. Why can't the library be made to work with a variety of data shapes, interpreting appropriately? For example, to work with a linear regressor I need to do

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
x = np.random.rand(10).reshape(-1,1)
y = np.random.rand(10).reshape(-1,1)
regr = LinearRegression()
regr.fit(x,y)
```

but if I want to use a support vector regressor, then I don't reshape the independent variable:

```
from sklearn.svm import SVR
x = np.random.rand(10).reshape(-1,1)
y = np.random.rand(10)
regr = SVR()
regr.fit(x,y)
```

I presume there is some reason why the library is designed in this way; can anyone illuminate me?

Comment: I dont get any errors when using `x = np.random.rand(10).reshape(-1,1), 
y = np.random.rand(10)` with any of your specified estimators. Both `SVR` and `LinearRegression` can take y with (n,) or (n,1).

Comment: So you can run the above with `x=np.random.rand(10)` and `y=np.random.rand(10)`? I get a `ValueError` when I try to do that. What version of `scikit-learn` are you using?

Comment: No. Not `X`. `X` must always be a 2-d vector of `[n_samples, n_features]`. I was talking about `y` (which is the only different code in your snippet above). `y` can be a column vector `[n_samples,1]` or simply `[n_samples,]`.

Comment: I get a `DataConversionWarning` when I use `SVR` with a column vector where `y.shape = (n_samples,1)`. As for `X`, I'm still unclear on why the `sklearn` doesn't automatically understand that if I pass it something of the shape `(n,)` that `n_samples=n` and `n_features=1`.

Comment: Yes, I do get a warning for y. For more clarity, I have added an answer. Hope it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `y = np.random.rand(10)`, y is a **one dimensional array** of `[10,]`. It doesnt matter if its a row vector or column vector. Its just a vector with only one dimension. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27866402/why-numpy-has-dimension-n-instead-of-n-1-only) and [this too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16995071/numpy-array-that-is-n-1-and-n) to understand the philosophy behind it.

Its a part of "**numpy philosophy**". And sklearn depends on numpy.

As for your comment:-

> why sklearn doesn't automatically understand that if I pass it something of the shape (n,) that n_samples=n and n_features=1

sklearn **may not** infer whether its `n_samples=n and n_features=1` or other way around (`n_samples=1 and n_features=n`) based on X data alone. It may be done, if y is passed which may make it clear about the `n_samples`.

**But that means changing all the code which relies on this type of semantics and that may break many things, because `sklearn` depends on `numpy` operations heavily.**

You may also want to check the following links where similar issues are discussed.

- https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/4509
- https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/4512
- https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/4466
- https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/5152