# Not understanding why a column has become a row in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I've just started learning Numpy. I'm already confused as to why the orientation has changed.

Here's my program:

```
import numpy as np
arr=np.random.random((5,5))
print(arr[-1,:])
```

which shows:

```
array([0.79859069, 0.93861609, 0.57585538, 0.87907495, 0.00705881])
```

Now to find the **column** with the maximum value on the last row of `arr`

```
# Find the max value column in the last row
maxlastvalcol=np.unravel_index(np.argmax(arr[-1,:]),arr[-1,:].shape)
```

which gives the answer:

```
(1,)
```

My understand of numpy is that it's orientation is

> (row,column)

So here I've gone from a column to a row. 0.93861609 is in column 1 of that last row. But the output is showing as row 1.

I was expecting to see the result be:

```
(,1)
```

What has happened?

Comment: could you try typing `(,1)` on the console/interpreter. What do you see? what about `(1,)`?

Comment: When a shape is listed as `(n,)`, that is a 1-dimensional array, so there is no sense of a row or column.

Comment: See [numpy array that is (n,1) and (n,)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16995071/numpy-array-that-is-n-1-and-n) for differences between the two.

Comment: given this, does that mean I need to **just know** that I need to use the number as the column in a further lookup of the array? Or is there some internal knowledge in the code that tells me it should be a column that I use the number for?

Comment: You need to know that it is the column. But really, in this case you should just be doing `maxlastvalcolindex = np.argmax(arr[-1,:])`. There's no need to deal with unraveling.

Comment: Shape is a `tuple`, e.g. `(2,3)`.  A single element tuple is writen as `(3,)`.  It's the comma that makes a tuple, moreso than the `()`.  This i python 102 :)  `(,3)` is not valid python.  Indexing with a scalar removes a dimension, e.g. `arr[1,:]` is 1d.  numpy` doesn't really have a `column vactor` unless you count a `(n,1)` shape, which is really a 1 column array.